# Need high quality preview with using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

using UIImagePickerController with:
sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera

I need the media that is being recorded to be saved with
videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeLow

I would like the video preview screen to have higher quality similar to what you see when using 
videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh

record at low quality but present preview at high quality.. is this possible using UIImagePickerController?